# An error occurred while calling o1964.collectToPython. : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I am trying to convert a spark RDD to Pandas DataFrame.

```
from pyspark.ml.regression import GBTRegressor

gbt = GBTRegressor(featuresCol="features",labelCol="Price", maxIter=10)
gbtModel = gbt.fit(training_data)
predictions_gbt = gbtModel.transform(testing_data)

predictions_gbt.select("features", "Price", "prediction").show()

prediction_gbt_test = gbtModel.transform(finalized_test_data)

prediction_gbt_test.toPandas()
```

This code produced an error:-

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1964.collectToPython.: 
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 166.0 failed 1 
times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 166.0 (TID 166, 86f0177ce5fa, executor driver): 
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined 
function(GBTRegressionModel$$Lambda$3519/181923952:
```

Can anyone help me, in solving this "Job aborted" kind of error.